# labjs not loading google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, labjs

I noticed that I am unable to load the google maps js libraries using labjs. I.e.

```
$LAB.script("//maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/jslibraries=geometry&v=3&sensor=false").wait()
```

is not working for me (library is not available in my code) and I have to explicitely do

```
<script src="//maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&v=3&sensor=false"></script>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

LAB.js can load Google Maps as long as you include a `callback` parameter, e.g.

```
window.noop = function() {};
$LAB.script("//maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/jslibraries=geometry&v=3&sensor=false&callback=noop").wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two urls are not the same. Did you check it?

Comment: Indeed! Anyway, I turned to requirejs in the mean time. Thanks!